# Textures on top of other textures when using VBOs

Tags: opengl, textures, lwjgl, decal-system

I'm currently making a cube style game. With chunks being drawn with VBOs. I'd like to know if there is a way to create an overlay texture on top of the existing texture without the need to rebuild the VBO. This is required to show activity in a cube (think of Minecraft when destroying a block and the little cracks start spreading).

I believe these are called "decals" but I've not found how to use them with VBOs. So how do I draw decals on OpenGL VBO drawn cubes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to render your VBO with two textures: one as the diffuse map (the block texture) and one showing the crack.

You can combine them in a shader:

```
// GLSL fragment shader

#version 130

uniform sampler2D texDiffuse;
uniform sampler2D texCrack;
uniform float uniCrackAmount; // between 0 and 1

in vec2 vertTexCoord;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    vec4 color_diffuse = texture(texDiffuse, vertTexCoord);
    vec4 color_crack = texture(texCrack, vertTexCoord);

    fragColor = color_diffuse + (color_crack * uniCrackAmount);
}
```

Comment: I could see that working if I was only drawing one cube. But how am I supposed to only draw the cracked texture on the faces of the cube I want, out of hundreds of cubes? Note that it could need to be multiple cubes as well.

Comment: Use a vertex attribute. Give each vertex of a cube a float that tells the shader to draw a certain amount of cracked texture on top of it.

Comment: So the vertex attribute goes into the VBO? Seems like it's not a very good solution. That could add thousands of floats, just for the handful of floats I'd want to utilize. Any non shader options?

Comment: Well, you wanted to render thousands of cubes, so whatever solution you come up with, it's going to cost a bit of memory. ;)

Comment: Thousands of floats is not a huge memory overhead.  We're talking kilobytes here; this isn't 1996.  Sometimes trading extra memory usage is a fair exchange for increased performance or flexibility.

Comment: I wanted to avoid getting too reliant on shader code for as long as possible so I could still develop on my laptop (which doesn't support shaders). Surely there must be a simple non-shader solution to this, since Minecraft doesn't use shaders. Can you explain how the vertex attribute works? I've not seen how that's implemented into VBOs.

Comment: @GameDev-er Just curious: is your laptop really really old or do you have outdated drivers? I know for a fact that without updated drivers, Windows reports support up to OpenGL 1.3. But even my girlfriend's netbook (from 2009) supports OpenGL 2.1, which does have shaders.

Comment: @knight666 It's more of a business laptop, so the video card is not made for 3D graphics. I guess I could try updating the drivers but I don't think that'll work.

Comment: Even a business laptop is - at worst - going to have some relatively recent Intel integrated graphics.  These support ARB assembly shaders all the way back to the 910/915 (from 2005/2006) and GLSL from roughly the 965 onwards.  For running on that kind of machine D3D may turn out to be a better option though.

Comment: A big problem with this approach is that if you have a large number of decals (i.e. a large number of textures you want to overlay onto a mesh) then you quickly hit the `GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS` limit (on my machine the maximum is 16).

Answer (score 2):

For a non-shader solution you could draw in two batches.  First of all you flag the cubes in the current scene that need the overlay texture - this can be done during your scene tree traversal or other scene setup.  Then draw the regular cubes using your normal draw routine.  Finally draw the overlay-textured cubes using multitexturing - you can experiment with a decal or interpolate TexEnv for this.

The VBO setup would just use the same set of texcoords for both texture units; something like this (not intended as copy-and-paste code):

```
glClientActiveTexture (GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnableClientState (GL_TEXTURE_COORD_POINTER);
glTexCoordPointer (2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof (myvertextype), (void *) 12);

glClientActiveTexture (GL_TEXTURE1);
glEnableClientState (GL_TEXTURE_COORD_POINTER);
glTexCoordPointer (2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof (myvertextype), (void *) 12);

// drawing stuff

glClientActiveTexture (GL_TEXTURE1);
glDisableClientState (GL_TEXTURE_COORD_POINTER);

glClientActiveTexture (GL_TEXTURE0);
glDisableClientState (GL_TEXTURE_COORD_POINTER);
```

But otherwise - yeah - the shader-based solution would be preferable.  Aside from those ClientActiveTexture calls going away (which is always a good thing) you've got much better control over the type of blend you do between the two textures.

Comment: Thanks mh01 I'd vote plus for your answer but I don't have the rep. So all I can say for now is thanks!

Comment: And LO!  You have rep.

Comment: Just 9 more points and I'll have enough! Thanks.